# ajax check button is clicked from a dynamically populated list of buttons

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I am new to ajax and I have a json response from django with a list of names to be displayed as a list of buttons. I want to disable the button once it is clicked.

Below is the html code I currently write, the button display successfully but it does not do the disable button action.

I would also like to ask what is the scope of this `onclick` function? Does the function dies at the end of the curly bracket `}`? Or does this function check even it is out of scope?

```html
<h3>User List:</h3>
<ul id="userLists"> </ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        // getUserList is a django views where it query the database and returns JsonResponse of the user's name
        url: "{% url 'getUserList' %}",
        success: function(response){
        $("#userLists").empty();
        // Create a list according to number of users in json
        for (var key in response.users){
            var temp="<button type=\"button\", name=\""+ response.users[key].user +"\", class=\"btn btn-outline-danger\">" + response.users[key].user + "</button>";
            $("#userLists").append(temp);


            // Here I want to do when clicked, it disables the button and leave others as is.
            // Current implementation does not work...

            document.getElementsByName(response.users[key].user).onclick =
            function(){document.getElementsByName(response.users[key].user).prop('disabled', true)};

            };
        }
    });
})
```

I have also tried the following implementation, it does not work...

```
if(document.getElementsByName(response.user[key].user).clicked == true){
    document.getElementsByName(response.user[key].user).prop("disabled", true);
};
```

Thanks all.

Comment: There is an obvious quote issue in your code... Can you fix that first?

Comment: `onclick` is a property of a DOM element to store the reference to a function to execute at each click on that element. It may also be trigered by a click on a child.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? :)

Comment: Should I write another function and search for all the childs under `id="userLists"` and do it from there?

Comment: Hint about the quote issue to fix: You are using double quote `"` for the string to be assigned to `temp`. And inside the string, you use single quotes. -- Now you have some uselessly escaped single quotes... And some double used where it should be single. Clear enought?

Comment: So in javascript it is like C++ where `char` needs to be single quote and `string` as double quote?

Comment: It can be one or the other... BUT, is has to be consistent for one string. You choose: one is the inner and one is the outer. But not a weird mix.

Comment: I have fixed the quote issue. Thanks!

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: The browser console does not complain but there is no action (blank out when clicked) still..

Comment: I think it is because `onclick` is in a loop and this object gets replaced on each loops? No idea how to fix this hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a node list ... So a collection of matching elements.
That is why `.onclick` and `.prop("disabled", true)` have no effect.

if `response.users[key].user` is to be unique, you can safely use `document.getElementsByName(response.user[key].user)[0]`.
So add `[0]` to target the first match.

About quotes *messing-with*, you may be interested in reading about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Many thanks for your help!!!! On top of that, I found out I can't use `prop("disabled", true)` so I replaced with `setAttribute("disabled", true)` for some reason if it is inside `success:` it is not jquery but DOM element. No wonder the console don't complain and no action

Comment: Yes... `.prop` is a method that applies on a jQuery object. Nice you found it! ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I am learning jquery and django from reading in stackoverflow. Is there any more proper materials to learn from? I digress..

Comment: Now if you want, you could stick to jQuery: ```$(`[name='${response.users[key].user}`].on("click", function(){ $(this).prop("disabled", true) })```

Comment: Best references are [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/).